# Why is this powershell script for tagging Azure VMs with tags from a csv file failing?

Tags: azure, powershell, csv, tags

I am trying to tag already deployed Azure VMs with tags from a CSV file. The script should be able to find the VMs using my RG and VM columns, assign tags from Company, DNS, CN and Type columns and replace the old CN tags (if they exist).

I found this script and modified it for my needs, but I cannot manage to make it work.

```
$csv = import-csv "C:\Powershell scripts\Tagging\Tagging.csv"

$csv | ForEach-Object {
    # Retrieve existing tags
    $tags = (Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName -Name $_.RG -ResourceType "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines" -Name $_.VM).Tags

    # Define new value pairs from CSV
    $newTags = @{
        company     = $_.Company
        dns         = $_.DNS
        type        = $_.Type
        CN          = $_.CN
    }

    # Add new tags to existing set (overwrite conflicting tag names)
    foreach($CN in $newTags.Keys){
        $tags[$_] = $newTags[$_]
    }

    # Update resource with new tag set
    Set-AzureRmResource  -ResourceGroupName -Name $_.RG -Name $_.VM -Tag $tags -ResourceType "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines" -verbose
}
```

---

my CSV file looks something like this:

```
Company,DNS,Type,CN,RG,VM
CompanyOne,VM1,Test,10917,machine774_rg,machine774
CompanyTwo,VM2,Development,10917,machine776_rg,machine776
...
```

Powershell throws these errors at me when trying to run the script:

```
Get-AzureRmResource : Missing an argument for parameter 'ResourceGroupName'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.String' and try again.
At line:3 char:34
+     $tags = (Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName -Name $_.RG -Reso ...
+                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-AzureRmResource], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.GetAzureResourceCmdlet

Cannot index into a null array.
At line:15 char:9
+         $tags[$_] = $newTags[$_]
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

Comment: Just as the error show, you miss the value of the parameter `-ResourceGroupName`. Try again with the value.

Comment: I tried adding -ResourceGroupName $_.RG but it still shows errors like: "The Azure PowerShell session has not been properly initialized.  Please import the module and try again." Also, the "cannot index into a null array" is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part `-ResourceGroupName -Name $_.RG` is wrong, it should be like below:

`Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $_.RG -ResourceType "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines" -Name $_.VM`

Also the `Set-AzureRmResource` command should be:

`Set-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $_.RG -ResourceType "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines" -Name $_.VM`

Comment: @Bogdan Where did you run the script?

Comment: I am running it through VSCode. Also tried running it in Powershell ISE on my computer but same errors occur.

Comment: @Bogdan Run your powershell ISE as admin, uninstall the old `AzureRm` module via `Uninstall-Module -Name AzureRm`, and [install the new `Az` module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-2.4.0), then use `Get-AzResource` and `Set-AzResource` instead of the old commands.

Comment: @Bogdan No need to modify the whole script, just need to use `Enable-AzureRmAlias` at first line of your script.

Comment: @Bogdan why you delete your comment again and again?

Comment: Because I realized that I only need to modify 2 commands. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Bogdan well, I recommend you to migrate it to Az, because the old AzureRm was deprecated.

Comment: It seems to be working great with Az. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Bogdan Glad it helps.